# LinkedIn login failing: OAuth callback URL was not confirmed

Tags: authentication, linkedin-api

I have got LinkedIn login functionality on my website. However, last week it stopped working, en has not worked since. At first I believed it was maintenance, but since it has been a week and I can not find anything about the api being down, I decided to ask about it.

With a little tinkering I was able to get the following error:

> Your_LinkedIn_Network_Will_Be_Back_Soon.
>   We\\'re getting things cleaned up.
>   We\\'ll be back soon.

Also: OAuth callback URL was not confirmed by the LinkedIn end-point

Url: http://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/requestToken?scope=r_basicprofile+r_emailaddress+rw_nus

Any idea as to what is going wrong? I tried the LinkedIn dev forum, but that is overrun with spam..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that the urls used to perform de CURL requests, all had http. However, linkedin probably changed this, now the only thing that works is urls with **https**.

In short: Replace all linkedin urls with https urls